Redirect loop from my local server to Spotify API, back again, and so forth
One of my assignments for my class is to create a React app which helps users search the Spotify library for songs and then add them to a custom playlist. That playlist can then be sent back and saved to their Spotify account, with playlist name and all chosen songs.
When I launch the server, and am alerted that there's no access token (and then go through to authorization), the browser starts pinging between the authorization URL and my local server. When it returns to my server, it first goes to a version with the frontend of the site live and the access token in the URL, and then redirects to the generic server url (http://localhost:3000/callback). This creates a mind-numbing redirect loop.
To extract the accessToken from the authorization URL, I employ a useEffect hook on mount. I think this hook is where the problem is, but I can't quite figure it out (neither can my internet searches, nor chatGPT, hence posting here).
I believe the issue lies in the currentTime forever being 3600 seconds behind the total expirationTime of the token, due to expirationTime = tokenExpiration + currentTime. I think this is causing a logic fart, and in turn the redirect loop. I believe I need to take somewhat of a snapshot of the currentTime, and use this as a static variable, but I don't know how.
I've pasted the useEffect below - any help would be much appreciated.
useEffect:
useEffect(() => {
    let keyValuePairs = window.location.hash.substring(1).split('&');
    let accessTokenPair = keyValuePairs.find(pair => pair.startsWith('access_token'));
    let tokenExpirationPair = keyValuePairs.find(pair => pair.startsWith('expires_in'));
  
    if (accessTokenPair) {
      let extractedAccessToken = accessTokenPair.split('=')[1];
      setAccessToken(extractedAccessToken); 
  
      if (tokenExpirationPair) {
        let tokenExpiration = parseInt(tokenExpirationPair.split('=')[1]);
        let currentTime = Math.floor(Date.now() / 1000);
        let newExpirationTime = currentTime + tokenExpiration;
        console.log('newExpirationTime: ' + newExpirationTime + 'currentTime: ' + currentTime);
  
        if (newExpirationTime < currentTime) {
          alert('Access token expired. Please login again.');
          setAccessToken(''); // reset token
        } else {
          console.log('Token is valid');
          setExpirationTime(newExpirationTime); 
        }
      }
    } else {
      alert('No access token found. Redirecting to login.');
      window.location.href = url; 
    }
    window.history.replaceState(null, document.title, window.location.pathname + window.location.search);
  }, []);

  function isTokenExpired() {
    const currentTime = Math.floor(Date.now() / 1000);
    return currentTime > expirationTime;
  };

I expect the authorization url to return to my http://local:3000/callback + {access_token} url, and not keep redirecting

What is expirationTime in your included code snippet? When/where is isTokenExpired called? Can you [edit] to include a complete [mcve] of the relevant code you are working with and any debugging details and reproduction steps you may have? I invite you to also take the [tour] and review Help/How to Ask to learn additional tips to improve the quality of your post.
